# How to get trigger (source) elements id from class methods?

Tags: javascript, events

From any elements (like ) onclick event that fires a function i can easly get id with

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

But i don't know how to get it inside a namespaced objects method.
I try like below, but a js error thrown.

```
var evraklarPanel = {};
evraklarPanel.Formlar = {
    yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm: function(e){
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    }   
}
```

I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

Comment: Are you using `evraklarPanel.Formular.yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm` as an event listener? Otherwise, no event object will be passed. BTW, what language is that? Also, your function gets `e` as an argument, but you're looking for the target at `event` (should be `e` too).

Comment: I am sorry. Language is javascript. And called from <a> code is: '<a style="color: white; font-weight:bold;" id="yeniEvraktipiGrubuEklemeBagi" title="Yeni evrak tipi grubu kaydet" href="javascript:evraklarPanel.Formlar.yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm(event)">+</a>'

Comment: You should be using `var target = et.target || e.srcElement` in this case. I was asking about the language of words like `evraklarPanel`.

Comment: `var evraklarPanel={};`
`evraklarPanel.Formlar={`
`yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm: function(e){`
`var evtobj=window.event? event : e;`
`alert(evtobj.id);`
`}}`

Comment: @bfavaretto lang is Turkish :)

Comment: Just change `event` to `e` on the js code you showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get the error is:

You pass the `e` as the event variable, but use `event` inside the function.

Working code:

```
var evraklarPanel = {};
evraklarPanel.Formlar = {
    yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm: function(e){
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Still getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: The way this code is right now, you should not be getting that. I think it may be a different part of your code using the same logic. Make sure that the console references the line you put this code on.

Comment: When i use directly the triggers `id` while calling function, it works. But if i put `event` and try handle it as an argument with the code `var target = e.target || e.srcElement;` error thrown.

Comment: According to *common sense*, replace `e` with `event` if it's explicitly needed. What I wrote works as is, just change it so it'll work well when implemented.

Comment: Stupid me! The source element is anchor and there is href not onclick event. Thank you very much. `<a style="color: white; font-weight:bold;" id="yeniEvraktipiGrubuEklemeBagi" title="Yeni evrak tipi grubu kaydet" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="evraklarPanel.Formlar.yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdiKayitForm(event)">+</a>` solves.